# How do I use escape characters in Xpath in C#, to find an element using its text having aingle & double quotes in it?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

When the webpage has text test'"message { **both single & double quotes in it**}. I have to find it using Xpath

As many said, in forums I looked in for the right approaches, tried using '' as escape character. But it didn't work, as expected!

Hence my attempts & errors are below & How do I achieve the expected result ?

[the escape character didn't help in locating the element within browser DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBNLL.jpg) Still I tried in script, to see any miracle happens, But just the errors.

1. Attempt with 'single escape character'

`d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()=\"test\"message\"]"));`

Error: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[text()="test"message"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[text()="test"message"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

2. Attempt with 'double escape character' as the scripting language is c#

`d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()=\"test\\\"message\"]"));`

Error: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression `//div[text()="test\"message"]` because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string `//div[text()="test\"message"]` is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: @DebanjanB why???? How that will improve this question? Will it make any more unique that dozens of other "XPath mixed quotes" questions?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Considering Selenium's usage of xpath v1.0 I'm sure taking into account the ancestor/parent/sibling elements there can be better xpaths/cssSelectors.

Comment: Due to the fact that this was marked as duplicate, i am adding the solution that worked for me here as common. In case someone landed in this question, 1. Split the element text based on quotes type - like, actual text <test'message"on'web> to be splitted as < test' message" on' web> or similar 2. use combined contains with alternative quotes as outside quotes